# Организация SFTP Windows Server

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, openssh

в администрировании Windows Server не силен

хотелось бы организовать безопасный обмен файлами между рабочей машиной и сервером Windows по защищенному протоколу передачи файлов SFTP (Secure FTP)

выполняю следующие действия:

1. устанавливаем *Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server**
2. проверяем *Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH.Ser*'*
3. *Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'*
4. *Start-Service sshd*
5. *New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22*
6. *restart-service sshd*

при авторизации через WinSCP, используя данные учетной записи администратора сервера Windows, получаем access denied

Comment: Ну а если просто по ssh тусануть - чё пишет? Ещё можно `-vvv` добавить.

Comment: спасибо что откликнулись на мою проблему. к сожалению при подключении через ssh получаю такую же ошибку. правильно ли я понимаю, что подключение может быть выполнено по логину и паролю локального аккаунта сервера без созданных сертификатов, если разрешить авторизацию по паролю?

Comment: Ну я пользуюсь "родным" ссх в линуксе - и там просто введи логи и пасс и всё поедет. Про особенности работы в винде - хз. Можешь попробовать вот эту штуку поковырять: https://github.com/drakkan/sftpgo. Новость на opennet: https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=53311